# How set my local database properly to be deployed to Heroku?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, heroku, cleardb

I have deployed my first Laravel blog into Heroku. I have added ClearDB as the remote database for Heroku. The problem is it comes out error 500 as in the link below:
https://laravel-raj-blog.herokuapp.com/blog

How do I properly set my database to enable login, post blog, register function work properly?